# Putting a List into a datatable column in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to display values from two different column in one `datatable` column. Is it possible to add them into a `List` and put the `List` into a `datatable` column?

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

              dt.Columns.Add("FullName");
              dt.Columns.Add("StudentId");

              foreach (var studentSubject in studentSubjects)
              {
                  dt.Columns.Add(studentSubject.ToString());
              }

              foreach (var g in groups)
              {
                  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                  dr["FullName"] = g.FullName;
                  dr["StudentId"] = g.StudentId;

                  foreach (var sc in g.ExamScore)
                  {

                      List<SubjectProperty> listSubjectProperty = new List<SubjectProperty>();

                      listSubjectProperty.Add(new SubjectProperty
                      {
                          SubjectId = sc.SubjectId,
                          Score = sc.ExamScore
                      });

                      dr[sc.SubjectName] = listSubjectProperty;
                  }

                  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: You'll find the answer to your question if you read the "remarks section": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did not get anything from it. My focus is here: `dr[sc.SubjectName] = listSubjectProperty;`. A sample code will help.

Comment: Is `List<T>` listed in the list of supported types? If *yes* then it's possible. If *no* then it's not possible. I'll give you a hint: `no`

Comment: Only one of the values is meant to show. The other value will be used as a parameter.

Comment: If only one column is meant to be displayed, then simply hide the other column. If you are using `DataGridView` then you can change the column visiblity to false on it.

Comment: I am using `angular` for my binding. If I put `dr[sc.SubjectName] = sc;` I get: `{SubjectName=Agricultural Science,ExamScore=56,SubjectId=6}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("A List Object", typeof(List<string>));

            List<string> names = null;

            names = new List<string>(new string[] {"John", "Mary"});
            dt.Rows.Add(names);

            names = new List<string>(new string[] { "Bob", "Carol", "Ted", "Alice" });
            dt.Rows.Add(names);

            names = new List<string>(new string[] { "Harry", "Sally"});
            dt.Rows.Add(names);
        }
    }
}
​
```